# Heard of Chamber of Chartered Java Professionals International?

Tags: software, degree, reputation, bachelor

I'm Java course which they said to me that they can arrange a Bachelor's degree from "The Chamber of Chartered Java Professionals International."

I did a little research my own, and from what I can see, they don't really have any verifiable information to confirm their existence.

1. Is there such chamber that can give people a degree?
2. If they can, is it a reputable degree?

My course is covers regular software engineering, including generic languages and sometimes specific languages. I also submitted a few assignments, and projects to the institute that I'm following the course with. From what I understand, they can make them equivalent to their degree requirements. However, their reputation and existence remain mysterious and I chose not to rely on what the institute says, which of course, technically, is a business.

Comment: Looks bogus to me. according to Google Maps, their "USA Coordinating Office" seems to be an apartment building.

Comment: If it sounds like bogus and looks like bogus, it is bogus. Stay clear as soon as possible to not lose any more money. The only reliable Java certifications are from Oracle and even Oracle does not claim to give BSc degrees.

Comment: Consider coding bootcamps instead if you prefer a non-conventional (non physical college) route - many are free these days; and to have to show something, coursera and such.

Comment: Any class in which the instructors/organizer offer you this must itself be considered suspect. I know, you didn't want to hear that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, degrees are given by universities, technological institutes, and other similar **accredited** institutes of higher learning. A degree without such an accreditation in place offers extremely limited value.

While this does appear to be a "real" organization, it does not appear to have any accreditation, which would make its degrees worthless junk.

Answer (score 12):

> Heard of Chamber of Chartered Java Professionals International?

### No.

> 2. If they can [offer a degree], is it a reputable degree?

### No.

Answer (score 3):

According to my knowledge, this chamber is owned by IJTS (a private sole owner company provides Java courses) in Sri Lanka.

Not reputed.